# Chrome get stuck on a page with many hidden radio buttons

Tags: google-chrome, radio-button

I have a page which dynamically creates radio buttons.
The page can sometimes be hidden (it's one of number of sub pages presented only when clicking a corresponding menu item).

The number of radio buttons on this page can be high on special cases (about 3000 radio buttons). When it does, Chrome is having trouble handling it.

When the sub page, containing the radio buttons is visible, you barely notice the slow reaction of the browser (but when you compare it to Firefox you understand it's there)

The problem is when the sub page is **not** visible. The browser almost doesn't respond...(it takes a few *minutes* to see a respond to a mouse click or event a mouse hover)

Firefox - doesn't have any problem with this page.
IE8 - gets a little slow when the radio buttons are displayed, but bearable.

I'm thinking of changing the entire design of this page, but I am trying to understand this problem.
Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: Are you trying to torture your users? Clearly this is a Chrome failsafe mechanism to preserver the user's sanity. I'm sorry for Firefox users, though.

Comment: I guess I'll go for the redesign option... Thanks all

Comment: http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-bugs/browse_thread/thread/654b279d5d00de97/6fe0e6f21508f79c?lnk=raot

Answer (score 3):

I cannot think of one situation where having 3000 radio buttons is normal. You should consider a redesign. Folks at Google who made Chrome probably haven't tried to tackle a problem like this since your situation is very corner case.

Answer (score 2):

3000 radio buttons on a page? While it may be an interesting intellectual exercise to figure out why chrome is choking on it, the solution is to redesign your page.

Comment: I figured those will be the answers I'll get to this question.... What about situation where you have several hidden pages and each one of them has several radio buttons, you will get the same result